# Check for key down in OpenGL Haskell

Tags: haskell, opengl, functional-programming

I am fairly new at Haskell and I am trying to create a small game in my free time.

[This tutorial](https://wiki.haskell.org/OpenGLTutorial2) does a great job of explaining how it works, and I can get the entire thing running smoothly. However, whenever they make things move in the example, they manipulate the entire viewport.

What I want for my game, is to change the data it displays when pressing a key.

Instead of this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  (_progName, _args) <- getArgsAndInitialize
  _window <- createWindow "Hello World"
  displayCallback $= display
  reshapeCallback $= Just reshape
  keyboardMouseCallback $= Just keyboardMouse
  mainLoop
```

I tried:

```
import Graphics.UI.GLUT

main :: IO ()
main = do
  (_progName, _args) <- getArgsAndInitialize
  _window <- createWindow "Hello World"
  go [(1,1,1),(0.5,0.5,0.5)] -- Initial state
  mainLoop

go points = do
  displayCallback $= (display points) -- Parse points to draw lines between
  keyboardMouseCallback $= Just keyboardMouse
  return ()
    where
        keyboardMouse _key _state _modifiers _position = go ((0,0,0):points) 
        -- Defined here so I can reference 'go'

display :: [(GLfloat,GLfloat,GLfloat)] -> DisplayCallback
display points = do 
  clear [ColorBuffer]
  renderPrimitive Lines $
     mapM_ (\(x, y, z) -> vertex $ Vertex3 x y z) points
  flush
```

However, it only draws the first line. It doesn't redraw when I press a key.
So imagine that I match on the key pressed, and from there I determine which point to add to the list of points. Can I get that working here, I should be able to implement it in my game.

Comment: So is your `keyboardMouse` called? Put there `print something` and see if it prints when you press the button

Comment: I actually managed to get something working, by further reading and understanding the tutorial. I hoped for at stateless solution, but that doesn't seem to be possible.